# Differentiating an indirect function

Tags: calculus, derivatives

**Question:**

> Find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ if:
>   $$x^2 + y^2 = t + \frac{1}{t}$$ and $$x^4 + y^4 = t^2 + \frac{1}{t^2}$$

**Attempt:**
To find $dy \over dx$, we basically need to find $dy \over dt$ and $dx \over dt$. I differentiated both equations with respect to $t$ and attempted to solve for $dy \over dt$ and $dx \over dt$ as if they were two variables. However, the question got too long and the calculation too tedious. Surely there is an easier method.

Comment: Well, you could solve for t in the first equation (just a quadratic equation), and then plug your value of t into the second equation. Then you can use normal implicit differentiation. It's probably still messy, but maybe less so.

Comment: That didn't work well either. Or maybe I messed up somewhere, but solving for $t$ din't get a nice value. And then substituting it into the second, with the term of $t^2$ and $1\over t^2$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Square first equation:
$$
(x^2+y^2)^2 = \left(t+\frac1t\right)^2\Longrightarrow x^4 + y^4 + 2x^2y^2 = t^2 + \frac{1}{t^2} + 2,
$$
and we get $x^2y^2=1$, and $y=\pm 1/x$.

UPDATE

We cannot determine signs of $x$ and $y$ from conditions. And if you don't want to use $\pm$, we can rewrite answer:
$$
xy=\pm1\Longrightarrow d(xy)=0\Longrightarrow x\,dy + y\,dx = 0 \Longrightarrow \frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac xy
$$